# Python - writing nested json to Excel using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, excel, json-normalize

I would like to know what the best way to convert a json object (with nested key, value pairs) to an Excel spreadsheet using python and pandas without having to iterate through the key, value items and explixitly specify the values (`value['title']`).

I was looking at something like the following, but the output is not correct as it adds everything in the same line:

```
for key, val in input_json.items():
    df_nested = pd.json_normalize(input_json, meta=[key, [key, "title"], [key, "type"]])
    df_nested.to_excel(r"_other_files\xlsx_output.xlsx")
```

Thanks very much for any assistance.

My json looks as follows:

```
{
  "01ef5d399597441bb6d685087276e659": {
    "title": "Forbidden App",
    "type": "Code",
    "typeKeywords": [
      "Code",
      "Javascript",
      "Application"
    ],
    "description": null,
    "tags": [],
    "url": "//forbidden_app/index.html",
    "owner": "email@address.com",
    "created": "18/11/2020 03:42:33",
    "modified": "30/11/2020 12:53:05"
  },
  "d5208e83259e492aa4b37bcd235a8d8c": {
    "title": "Mobile App",
    "type": "Mobile",
    "typeKeywords": [
      "Mobile",
      "Published"
    ],
    "description": "This is a mobile application",
    "tags": [
      "Inspection",
      "Offline",
      "Survey"
    ],
    "url": "//mobile_app/index.html",
    "owner": "address@email.com",
    "created": "12/02/2021 10:24:12",
    "modified": "25/02/2021 15:02:34"
  }
}
```

My output Exel file should look like this:

| ID | Title | Type | Keywords | Description | Tags | URL | Owner | Created | Modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01ef5d399597441bb6d685087276e659 | Forbidden App | Code | ['Code', 'Javascript', 'Application'] | None | [] | //forbidden_app/index.html | email@address.com | 18/11/2020 03:42 | 30/11/2020 12:53 |
| d5208e83259e492aa4b37bcd235a8d8c | Mobile App | Mobile | ['Mobile', 'Published'] | This is a mobile application | ['Inspection', 'Offline', 'Survey'] | //mobile_app/index.html | address@email.com | 12/02/2021 10:24 | 25/02/2021 15:02 |

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')`, parse the json string if needed.